# How can I see the content of messages in my Qpid Broker Management console?

Tags: java, jms, amqp, qpid

I am using queues in a Java application in order to produce and consume messages that go through them.

I would like to check the content of the payload I send using the QPID Broker (documentation: http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-broker-j-7.0.3). I am viewing my Broker Manager through a link like this (please note the **http** - without **s** - in the link):

```
http://myServer:myHost/
```

When I try to open a message that I can see going through the queues where I'm sending it, I get this:

[image]

Unfortunately my development server can't be moved over an `HTTPS` connection, so I will have to stick to `HTTP`.

I've looked over the web to see if someone had my same issue, and didn't find much, the only tip I've found into another forum was to modify the `config.json` of the messaging broker in order to allow confidential operations on insecure channels:

```
{
    "name" : "HTTP",
    "port" : "${BROKER_HTTP_PORT}",
    "authenticationProvider" : "anonymous",
    "allowConfidentialOperationsOnInsecureChannels" : true, <-- ADDED BY ME
    "protocols" : [ "HTTP" ]
}
```

I have restarted the broker service after this change, but still I keep on getting the same message when opening a payload.

Does anybody have any idea to read the content of the payloads without actually doing it via a consumer?

Comment: any resolution?    *seems* my "publisher" connects and sends message... -but, my "consumer" appears to have received nothing but an empty message "shell"... e.g.,  printing out the "consumed" message looks like:  "Exchange[ID-LAPTOP-4LR4PMVQ-1577475921482-0-19]"  - rather than the original payload/text

Comment: @sairn none, I ended up dropping qpid in my solution...

Comment: sorry to hear.  but, I certainly do understand the frustration!  :-)   --thx!